# Kafka streaming: Default numbers of partitions in store changelog topic

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to configure number of partitions for the changelog topic, which backs up manualy created store?
I have DSL topology combined with Processor API for custom processing. I have store which is used in custom processor defined like this:

```
reservationStoreBuilder = Stores
            .keyValueStoreBuilder(
                Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(props.reservationStore),
                primitiveAvroSerde,
                genericAvroSerde
            ).withLoggingEnabled(HashMap()).withCachingEnabled()
```

Is it possible to configure the number of partitions in the changelog topic? If not how does this default?

Comment: It should match the same as the topic you're processing. You can't change it

Comment: In fact processor using this store consumes 2 topics, which are result of previous DSL toplogy processing and at the end they are repartitioned with KStream::repartition to one partition. But store is automatically created with 4 partitions ...

Comment: To be more clear, here is pseudocode. topic1 and topic2 have 4 partitions, but they are repartitioned to 1, and result is merged and processed in transform.
But changelog of store is automaticaly created with 4 partitions :



```
t1 = topic1.selectKey(key1).repartition(Repartitioned.numberOfPartitions(1));
t2 = topic2.selectKey(key1).repartition(Repartitioned.numberOfPartitions(1));
t1.merge(t2).transform(PaymentTransformer, store);
```